# An easy way to create videos for YouTube from mp3 files

Tags: video, conversion

Is there an easy way to convert multiple mp3 files to video files at once? I could of course use a simple video editor, but I was thinking more of an app that would take multiple mp3 files, set the preferred album cover image as "video", and convert them one after another without having to do the same process for each mp3 file manually. I would like this to be an offline app (not a web app). Which video format should I use for this (I would like to keep as much sound quality as possible)?

Comment: This is a piece of cake for FFMPEG.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Thanks to Brads recommendation, I used ffmpeg for the job. Here is a small bash script that converts all the mp3 files to mpeg4 avi files (a jpg image must be included in the folder):

```
#!/bin/bash
# Requires: ffmpeg
# Usage: ./convert.sh

for file in *.mp3;
do
    ffmpeg -i *.jpg -i "${file}" "${file%.*}.avi"
done
```

Some more info [here](https://superuser.com/questions/98980/ffmpeg-creating-video-for-youtube) and [here](http://www.crimulus.com/tag/upload-mp3-to-youtube/), but that didn't work for me.. All these options they used made it too complicated and it just didn't work - nothing would get converted (I would get files with audio but without the image in the video or videos with image but without audio, -loop option was unnecessary, -shortest option was unnecessary, works fine without it)..